# How to add a linear contraint between state variables to a current time Hamiltonian?

Tags: optimal-control, hamiltonian

Let's say I have an objective function $F$ with state variables $A,B,C$ and relative equations of motion, I can create the current time Hamiltonian with $H_C = F\{A,B,C\}+\alpha * \dot A+\beta * \dot B + \gamma \dot C$, where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are the 3 co-state variables (I'm omitting here the control variables).

But what if I also have a constraint that in each moment in time I must have something like $aA + bB + cC = k$ (where $a,b,c,k$ are fixed parameters) ? How do I set this constraint in the hamiltonian ?

Of course I could simply use only the $A,B$ variables, but then I still have an equation of motion for $C$ (in my application $A$, $B$ and $C$ are different land use areas).

Comment: I think Dorfman might do a similar thing in this paper but I'm not absolutely certain because it's been a long time since I read it.  Check it out and see if it helps. https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/88-737/optimal_control/papers/dorfman.pdf

Comment: In the meantime II have found [this](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/5458441/mod_resource/content/1/Aula%2013.pdf) where the constraint is simply added to the Hamilton to maximise with an ancillary variable, a bit like with the Lagrangian.

Comment: thanks. I'll check it out.